# division process with condition avoiding infinites python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, infinite

I have a question about the way I am handling this problem
What this code does is basically:

```
x3 = (x2-x1)/x1
```

where **x1** is the values of day **d**
where **x2** is the value of day **d+1**
and **x3** is a value that I am calculating based on previous values

When happens that my division is something like:
(0.5-0)/0 as it happens with day 2017-09-010 and POS_16_20_and 2017-09-011 it will be infinite, for example. I would like to use a condition with my division that if the value that I am dividing is zero then set **x3=x2** because I don't want infinite values

I would like to replace it with my last value then.

The code:

```
waps_df2 =  waps_df1-waps_df1.shift(1)
waps_df2 = waps_df2.fillna(0)
waps_x = waps_df2.div(waps_df1.shift(1))
waps_ad = waps_x.add(1)
waps_x3 = waps_ad.shift(+1)
```

My date frame:

```
produktname  POS_00_04  POS_04_08  POS_08_12  POS_12_16  POS_16_20  POS_20_24  
datum_von                                                                      
2017-09-09         0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0       0.00        0.0  
2017-09-10         0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0       0.00        0.0  
2017-09-11         0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0       0.05        0.0  
2017-09-12         0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0       0.06        0.0  
2017-09-13         0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0       0.00        0.0
```

I tried to use masks

```
waps_pos = waps_pos.mask((waps_df1!=0), waps_pos.div(waps_df1.shift(1))

waps_x = np.where(waps_df1.shift(1)>0, waps_pos.div(waps_df1.shift(1), waps_df1)
```

or

```
waps_x = np.where(waps_df1.shift(1)>0, waps_pos.div(waps_df1.shift(1), waps_df1)
```

Comment: `np.where(x1 > 0, (x2 - x1) / x1, x2)` should do.

Comment: @coldspeed waps_pr = waps_df1.where((waps_df1.shift(1)>0) & (waps_df1==0), waps_div, waps_df1) **but** ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). **why I got this bug?**

Comment: If I use np.where... this will return an array and not  date frame

Comment: waps_pos = waps_pos.mask((waps_df1!=0), waps_pos.div(waps_df1.shift(1))

waps_x = np.where(waps_df1.shift(1)>0, waps_pos.div(waps_df1.shift(1), waps_df1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
waps_df2 = waps_df1.sub(waps_df1.shift(1)).fillna(0)
print (waps_df2)
            POS_00_04  POS_04_08  POS_08_12  POS_12_16  POS_16_20  POS_20_24
datum_von                                                                   
2017-09-09        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0       0.00        0.0
2017-09-10        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0       0.00        0.0
2017-09-11        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0       0.05        0.0
2017-09-12        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0       0.01        0.0
2017-09-13        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0      -0.06        0.0

waps_x = waps_df2.div(waps_df1.shift(1))
print (waps_x)
            POS_00_04  POS_04_08  POS_08_12  POS_12_16  POS_16_20  POS_20_24
datum_von                                                                   
2017-09-09        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
2017-09-10        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
2017-09-11        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        inf        NaN
2017-09-12        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   0.200000        NaN
2017-09-13        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN  -1.000000        NaN
```

You can check inf values by [`numpy.isinf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isinf.html) and replace them to `waps_df1` by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
print (np.isinf(waps_x))
            POS_00_04  POS_04_08  POS_08_12  POS_12_16  POS_16_20  POS_20_24
datum_von                                                                   
2017-09-09      False      False      False      False      False      False
2017-09-10      False      False      False      False      False      False
2017-09-11      False      False      False      False       True      False
2017-09-12      False      False      False      False      False      False
2017-09-13      False      False      False      False      False      False

waps_x = waps_x.mask(np.isinf(waps_x), waps_df1)
print (waps_x)
            POS_00_04  POS_04_08  POS_08_12  POS_12_16  POS_16_20  POS_20_24
datum_von                                                                   
2017-09-09        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
2017-09-10        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
2017-09-11        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN       0.05        NaN
2017-09-12        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN       0.20        NaN
2017-09-13        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN      -1.00        NaN
```